# Moving a GameObject using tags not working Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know this is quite the noob question, but whatever, there's only one way to learn.

I've created an empty GameObject in Unity, attached a script that is supposed to move a cube(my player) and gave my cube the tag "Player". After creating the cube, I was hoping to be able to move the cube without having to put the script on the cube itself. When the script is on the cube, it moves without a problem (I know this is how it probably should be done, but for trying to learn new things I wanted to do it this way).

[Player Controller script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEoVN.png)

[Cube properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edmEZ.png)

After failing to find the answer through Google, any insight at all is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

---

Update!

---

Here's the code as text now, since it was asked for.

```
    public class GameCoreController : MonoBehaviour {

            private GameObject PlayerMove;
            public Rigidbody rb;

            void Start ()
            {
                 PlayerMove = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
                 rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); 
            }

            void Update()
            {
                 // character movement 
                 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
                 {
                      PlayerMove.transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.25f);
                 }

                 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
                 {
                      PlayerMove.transform.Translate(0, 0, -0.25f);
                 }

                 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
                 {
                      PlayerMove.transform.Translate(-0.25f, 0, 0);
                 }

                 if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
                 {
                      PlayerMove.transform.Translate(0.25f, 0, -0);
                 }
             }
```

I've updated the code from before to include `PlayerMove.transform.Translate` but I still have the same issue with the cube note moving. I've also included screenshots of my scene with the cube and the GameCoreController; the empty GameObject holding the script that is supposed to control the cube.
[image: Cube scene] 
[image: GameVoreController scene]

Thanks again for the help guys.

---

Update 2!

---

After deleting the cube and re-insert it into the scene it now moves. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: @Caramiriel Sure can! Just updated the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the cube won't move because in your code you didn't move its `transform` but you move the `transform` of the gameobject that you attached this script to.

`transform.Translate` move the transform of the gameobject that this script attach to. So if you want to move the cube, all you need to do is change from `transform.Translate` to `PlayerMove.transform.Translate` which will move the transform of `PlayerMove` gameobject which is your cube with "Player" tag on it

Comment: Additionally, this script still needs to be attached *somewhere* in the scene (its a MonoBehaviour!).

Comment: @Draco18s The script is attached to an Empty GameObject in the scene. Will that work?

Comment: @K.J.Shamberger An empty game object is "somewhere in the scene" so yes.

Answer (score 0):

^ All of the above.  Plus, in the screenshot, your rigidbody is not set to "is kinomatic".  This means that physics will still be applied to it (like gravity).  Rule of thumb: If you have a moving object where collision is important, it will need a rigidbody and a collider.  If the object is not moved with physics commands (eg rigidbody.AddForce()) but rather manipulating the transform as you are, set the rigidbody "isKinomatic" property to true.

Comment: also rb= PlayerMove.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();